# Basic small Angular file structure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns, structure

**Question**

Can someone show me the correct way to lay out the structure for my first angular project?

**Overview**

This is my first Angular project, and i wish to get the structure correct before I go further.

I am building a form that has multiple sections and functions.

I have seen many different ideas online and mainly for large projects not for a small starter project so I hope someone can help me get starred.

**Current structure**

[image]

all the form files are different sections of my form.

**app.js**

```
// app.js
// create our angular app and inject ngAnimate and ui-router 
// =============================================================================
angular.module('formApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router'])

// configuring our routes 
// =============================================================================
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider

        // route to show our basic form (/form)
        .state('form', {
            url: '/form',
            templateUrl: 'form.html',
            controller: 'formController'
        })

        // nested states 
        // each of these sections will have their own view
        // url will be nested (/form/signup)
        .state('form.signup', {
            url: '/signup',
            templateUrl: 'form-signup.html'
        })

        // url will be /form/select
        .state('form.select', {
            url: '/select',
            templateUrl: 'form-select.html'
        })

        // url will be /form/type
        .state('form.type', {
            url: '/type',
            templateUrl: 'form-type.html'
        });

    // catch all route
    // send users to the form page 
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/form/signup');
})

// our controller for the form
// =============================================================================
.controller('formController', function($scope) {

    // we will store all of our form data in this object
    $scope.formData = {};

    // function to process the form
    $scope.processForm = function() {
        alert('awesome!');
    };

});
```

**test.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.user = {bankName: ''};

    $scope.banks = [{
        "name": "Bank A",
        "branches": [{
            "name": "Branch 1",
            "code": "1"
        }, {
            "name": "Branch 2",
            "code": "2"
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Bank B",
        "branches": [{
            "name": "Branch 3",
            "code": "3"
        }, {
            "name": "Branch 4",
            "code": "4"
        }, {
            "name": "Branch 5",
            "code": "5"
        }]
    }];

});
```

Comment: Take a look at this angular generator: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular

Comment: hmm yeoman looks interesting +1 thanks for the information

Comment: Take a look at [John Papa's LIFT Principle](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#application-structure-lift-principle). This will help you to get an idea about your application structure

Comment: Try angular-seed , it will help you to setup default folder structure for AngularApp [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed)

Comment: @Kanagu lots of information there +1

Answer (score 2):

Okay. Everyone has a different structure for their use and comfort

I am adding a image here see the folder structure in it, this is best for large projects

[image]

So My structure is something like this

If I have addRecords, authentication and engagement 3 different module(there're more but in this picture), So I have created folder for each module and created separate template, controller, service, module, css file. So this can be a separated module(app), add that module in the app.js

In authentication, It has sub modules like login, forgot, signup etc. so these goes to the sub folder and sub modules.

**NOTE:** Your way is good for small apps. You are adding all js to one folder than all css to other folder, same for html templates in 3rd folder.
But if you have separated module folder for each module, then it is easy while searching for things when your project grows in 100s of modules.

Comment: Nice, thanks. |I cant see this project getting large. but its nice to see a larger structure. with my current structure should i place the index outside of the app folder in my main project folder as atm I have Project> app ?

Comment: Basically index.html should be in main app folder. First folder where app start.

Comment: thanks have done, just trying to separate my controllers and modules atm finding it tricky to understand

Answer (score 2):

The best folder structure for angular app and style guide is provided by john papa
please refer to this link https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide